# Partial derivative at $(0,0)$ for norm function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: partial-derivative

See example (ii):

[image]

Shouldn’t it be that we have a limit of the quotient $\frac{\mid h\mid}{h}$ instead of $\frac{h}{\mid h\mid}$? Because we have:

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{h^2}}{h}=\frac{\mid h\mid}{h}.
$$

Technically, it doesn't matter of course, but I was just wondering if I interpreted something wrong?

Comment: No, you have not interpreted anything incorrectly. While it does not technically matter, the expression you have written will appear first in logical order when we proceed by definition.

Comment: @Sha I think you are right. The author probably confused the definition with the expressions for $\;f_x,\,f_y\;$ that he wrote just a few lines above...

Comment: The author probably confused nothing with nothing, instead, they simply were aware that $h/|h|$ and $|h|/h$ are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all $\dfrac{h}{\left| h \right|}$ is the same as $\dfrac{\left| h \right|}{h}$. More precisely:
$$\forall h > 0, \dfrac{h}{\left| h \right|} = \dfrac{\left| h \right|}{h} = 1 \\
\forall h < 0, \dfrac{h}{\left| h \right|} = \dfrac{\left| h \right|}{h} = -1$$

The author simply says that as the right limit is distinct from the left limit, we cannot have a limit at $0$.